# Will my files be erased if I use a recovery image on my Surface Pro?

Tags: windows, windows-8, microsoft-surface

I’m following the [official Microsoft instructions here](https://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us/support/warranty-service-and-recovery/downloadablerecoveryimage?productId=100110237) to attempt to restore my Surface Pro 2 from a Windows 10 Technical Preview from expiring. I’m going to copy the recovery image to a USB. Will it erase my files if I recover, refresh or reset my Surface Pro?

Because the page hides the information after you click download I'm adding a screen capture here:

[image]
[image]

The link in the last image points to [here](https://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us/support/warranty-service-and-recovery/usbrecovery?os=windows-10).

**UPDATE:**
Used the recovery USB to go to the command prompt and set the date to a few days earlier. It allowed me to boot up and haven't had any issues yet.

Comment: I haven't used Surface Pro but i am quite sure the above terminologies (recover, refresh,reset) mean the same everywhere. I would say, Yes if you recover or reset, no if you refresh

Comment: I know they are three different things, just wasn't sure if OP meant **system image recovery** when he said recover

Comment: Why don't you just update the Preview build, if you have wait until after the build expired, you are out of luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The screenshot you are showing states:

> **Important:** Creating a recovery drive will erase everything that’s
>   stored on your USB drive.

Yes, that makes sense. To create the USB recovery drive the software needs to wipe the whole USB flash drive. That has 100% nothing to do with the data stored on the Surface Pro itself in any way. It’s just saying the USB flash drive you will be using for the USB recovery drive is what needs to be wiped.

Once that’s done, you would boot your Surface Pro from that USB recovery drive and follow the rest of the steps.

> Will it erase my files if I recover, refresh or reset my Surface Pro?

Depends on which method you use. Here is how I am understanding [this official Microsoft page](https://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us/support/warranty-service-and-recovery/refresh-or-reset-surface-rt?os=windows-8.1-rt-update-3) on the topic; text comes from that page but my bullet points and summaries are here for clarity/succinctness:

- **Refresh:** Refreshing your Surface reinstalls Windows and keeps your personal files, settings, apps that came installed on your Surface, and apps that you installed from the Windows Store.
- **Reset:** A reset returns Surface to its factory settings. A reset reinstalls Windows and apps that came installed on your Surface. All of your personal files will be deleted, and your settings will be reset. All apps that you installed will be removed.

There doesn’t seem to be a mention of a “recovery” mode other than the fact that to either “refresh” or “reset” you need to start the Surface Pro “USB recovery drive” which you need to create.

I believe that a USB recovery drive would basically be the equivalent of a USB/CD live boot disk on a PC. And once you startup the Surface Pro from that USB recovery drive you will then have the option to either “refresh” or “reset” the Surface Pro.

So if you don’t want to lose the personal data stored on the Surface Pro, the “refresh” method seems like the way to go. But how that affects your Windows 10 Technical Preview from expiring? Your guess is as good as mine.